# Which set is this bag 2 from? White airplane pieces?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

Which set is it from? Can I build anything with it on its own? It says 2007 on the bag.

[image: a clear bag of various LEGO bricks]

Answer (score 3):

3367 space shuttle seems to match, although it is a 2011 set

https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=3367-1

The tail piece does not appear in older sets in white according to bricklink...

Comment: That's the one! Thank you so much. It seems that for some reason the copy right was in 2007. Secondary question, i got that bag in an other set i got from a charity shop. What would be the best way to get the pieces from the bag 1? Or shoukd i just give up the idea and leave the pieces to my son's imagination?

Comment: The year on the bag, might just be the year the bag was produced/designed. For getting the pieces from the other bag(s) of the set (and the pieces et al. - e.g. the sticket sheet - not in any bag), you can use bricklink, if you make a wish list I believe you can make bricklink tell you which seller has the most of the needed parts, but it's going to be a lot of work, and if you can't find one or two sellers that have everything, shipping costs might make it more expensive than just ordering the complete set.

Comment: More likely in my opinion that the 2007 is another code altogether than that the bag was produced/designed 4 years in advance...

Comment: The design of the bag (typography, placement of text, production mechanism) was copyrighted in 2007 and likely used from that year onwards until replaced with the next style bag (copyright 2011), which is used on some current sets still, even though it has been replaved by yet another design (with the white band down the middle) in 2017.